# Criteria.list() returns an empty collection, no query executed

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get a collection of Event.class objects, but criteria.list() returns an empty collection. I also have show_sql = true property, but there is no sql's in console

My hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- hibernate dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/inspector_database</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">********</property>
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

    <!-- Simple memory-only cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- <mapping class="mainobjects.Driver"/> -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="inspectorserver.entities.Driver"  resource="inspectorserver/entities/Driver.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="inspectorserver.entities.Event"  resource="inspectorserver/entities/Event.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="inspectorserver.entities.Violation" resource="inspectorserver/entities/Violation.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping class="inspectorserver.entities.Car" resource="inspectorserver/entities/Car.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Event.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 18.03.2016 21:32:29 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="inspectorserver.entities.Event" table="EVENT" lazy="false">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="eventDate" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="EVENTDATE" />
        </property>
        <property name="feeSum" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="FEESUM" />
        </property>
        <property name="driverLicenseNumber" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DRIVERLICENSENUMBER" />
        </property>
        <property name="carVINCode" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="CARVINCODE" />
        </property>
        <property name="syncStatus" type="int">
            <column name="SYNCSTATUS" />
        </property>


    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is how I get the collection:

```
Session session = MyHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Event.class);   
criteria.list(); //empty
```

Comment: what a console log ,Can you show any sql query in console ?

Comment: As I said, the problem is there is NO sql logs in console

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by removing class="inspectorserver.entities.Driver(Event, etc.)" from  tag